# Can anyone please give pdf link for Brahma Sutra Bhashya of Shri Adi Shankaracharya in Kannada?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, translation-request, brahma-sutras

Is there any online link available with Shri Adi Shankaracharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya in Kannada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It's available on Internet Archive.

**Brahmasutrabhashya with Shankaracharya commentary translated from Sanskrit to  Kannada Language by Sri Sachidanandendra Swamiji**

- [Part 1](https://archive.org/details/Sachidanandendra_Swamiji__Shankaracharya_-_Brahmasutrabhashya_-_1)
- [Part 2](https://archive.org/details/Sachidanandendra_Swamiji__Shankaracharya_-_Brahmasutrabhashya_-_2)

Comment: Oh man!! I was searching for it in Archove org. How did you get it?? Thanks a lot 

Comment: @VARUN He searched in archive.org while you searched in Archove org. That's why he was able to get it. :-D

Comment: @Pandya both the links point to the same book.  The first part is missing. Can you please look into that.